# Setting up IPv6 on Apache2

Tags: apache-2.2, ipv6, httpd.conf, virtualhost

Currently I have the "ports.conf" with the following content:

```
NameVirtualHost *:80
Listen 80

<IfModule mod_ssl.c>
    Listen 443
    NameVirtualHost *:443
</IfModule>

<IfModule mod_gnutls.c>
    Listen 443
</IfModule>
```

So to add IPv6 I have to change it to:

```
NameVirtualHost 91.64.99.215:80
Listen 91.64.99.215:80

NameVirtualHost [2a01:4f8:140:54e4::3]:80
Listen [2a01:4f8:140:54e4::3]:80

<IfModule mod_ssl.c>
    Listen 443
    NameVirtualHost 91.64.99.215:443
    NameVirtualHost [2a01:4f8:140:54e4::3]:443
</IfModule>

<IfModule mod_gnutls.c>
    Listen 91.64.99.215:443
    Listen [2a01:4f8:140:54e4::3]:443
</IfModule>
```

Is this correct?

My fear is that if I do this all vhosts set up like

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
     ServerName www.domain.tld
     ServerAlias domain.tld
     DocumentRoot /www/domain
</VirtualHost>
```

will go berserk. If this is not the case, doing

```
<VirtualHost *:80 [*]:80>
     ServerName www.domain.tld
     ServerAlias domain.tld
     DocumentRoot /www/domain
</VirtualHost>
```

should also make the domain available via IPv6?

I am a bit confused here and cannot make much out of the existing "examples" Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: This looks fine. What is the problem you are having with it?

Comment: There are several contradictory stetup examples out there. I just want to make sure that if I change "ports.conf" as described, that all the vhosts set up like
```text
<VirtualHost *:80>
     ServerName www.domain.tld
     ServerAlias domain.tld
     DocumentRoot /www/domain
</VirtualHost>
```
will still work like nothing was change at "ports.conf".

Comment: Why wouldn't they? What happened when you tested this?

Comment: I am utterly sorry. Having problems to add a comment with serveral lines and code blocks :(

I did not test so far, since there are active websites running. I am just worried that the * is to unspecific. I will give it a try now.

Comment: I get the following warning
```[warn] _default_ VirtualHost overlap on port 443, the first has precedence```
```[warn] NameVirtualHost 91.212.95.130:80 has no VirtualHosts``` I believe that as soon as I activate this everything goes down the sink. Obviously it has not VirtualHosts because they are all set up like ```<VirtualHost *:80>```

Comment: I am just worried that I will have to reconfigure all vhosts to ```<VirtualHost 91.64.99.215:80>``` before changing the "ports.conf". This appears to be a pretty inelegant solution. So basically the question is: Is there a configuration for "ports.conf" that avoids this?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You just need to change your `Listen` directives to:

```
Listen [::]:80
Listen [::]:443
```

while your

```
NameVirtualHost *:80
<VirtualHost *:80>
```

remain the same.

Note: `netstat -tln` will show apache listening only on `tcp6` / `:::80`; that is normal (it will also respond to IPv4 as before)